# Change video source depending on screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am trying to change my video source if my screen width is under 1000px.
Any help would be much appreciated as with my little knowledge with javascript  and Jquery i am not sure what to do from here.
Thanks.

My current code below:

HTML

```
    <video id="bg-vid" autoplay defaltmuted playsinline>
        <source id="v1" src="img/optimised/desktop-palmtrees.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="img/Palm_Trees.webm" type="video/webm" onerror="fallback(parentNode)">
    </video>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';
    if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
        var videoFile = 'img/optimised/desktop-palmtrees.mp4';
        var source = document.getelementbyid('v1');
        source.src = videoFile;
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 1000) {
        var videoFile = 'img/optimised/iphone-palmtrees.mp4';
        var source = document.getelementbyid('v1');
        source.src = videoFile;
    }
});
```

Comment: you have type error document.getElementById('v1');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, I added some `console.log()` for you to trace the `src` attribute.

```js
$(function(){
    console.log('before: '+$('#v1').attr('src'));
    if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
        var videoFile = 'img/optimised/desktop-palmtrees.mp4';
        $('#v1').attr('src',videoFile);
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 1000) {
        var videoFile = 'img/optimised/iphone-palmtrees.mp4';
        $('#v1').attr('src',videoFile);
    }
    console.log('after: '+$('#v1').attr('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="bg-vid" autoplay defaltmuted playsinline>
        <source id="v1" src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="img/Palm_Trees.webm" type="video/webm" >
    </video>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me, tried it in a new blank site as well just to be sure.

Comment: I added some `console.log()` for you to see it works.